# How to stop media player on click?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am trying to develop android sound application, I am sort of new into development so I am stuck on 1 little problem.
I made On Button click to play sound, but I want when I click on that button again, I want it to stop Media player. I would appreciate if you could help me with the script.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.prvi);

    final MediaPlayer mpButtonClick1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.spalshm);

    Button dugme = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dugme);
    dugme.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                mpButtonClick1.start();
        }
    });     
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(mpButtonClick1.isPLaying()){
    mpButtonClick1.start();
}else{
   mpButtonClick1.stop();
}
```

And as a general tip, check out the documentation of the classes you use, you might have found the solution yourself...
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#isPlaying()

Answer (score 0):

You can used `MediaPlayer.isPlaying()` to determine what your button should do when it is clicked.

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        if(mpButtonClick1.isPlaying())
        {
            mpButtonClick1.stop();
        }
        else
        {
            mpButtonClick1.start();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [isPlaying](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#isPlaying%28%29) method.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.prvi);

    final MediaPlayer mpButtonClick1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.spalshm);

    Button dugme = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dugme);
    dugme.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                if(mpButtonClick1.isPlaying())
                  stopPlaying();
                else
                  mpButtonClick1.start();
                 }
    });     
}


private void stopPlaying() {
        if (mpButtonClick1 != null) {
            mpButtonClick1.stop();
            mpButtonClick1.release();
            mpButtonClick1 = null;
       }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.prvi);

    final MediaPlayer mpButtonClick1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.spalshm);

    boolean isOn = false;

    Button dugme = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dugme);
    dugme.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            is(!isOn) { // if not playing
                mpButtonClick1.start(); // start
                isOn = true; // now it is
            } else { // otherwise it's already on
                mpButtonClick1.stop(); // turn it off
                isOn = false; // now it's off
            }
        }
    });     
}
```

Comment: This is -1 just because I'm not using `.isPlaying()`? Seriously? It's another way to do it and will work even if `.isPlaying()` *didn't* exist.